# Dúvida com uma query (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Boa tarde!

Eu tenho um conjunto de informações em um banco SQL Server (ainda estou aprendendo SQL Server), e preciso filtrar as informações que são retornadas para mim. São informações de funcionários de uma empresa (matricula, cpf, nome, cargo, situação, etc). Só que eu também possuo 2 campos chamados ano e mes, referentes ao ano e mês que aquele funcionário trabalhou. Eu gostaria de receber somente o último mês do último ano que aquele funcionário trabalhou, e não todos os meses. Por exemplo, existe um funcionário que trabalhou até do mês 06 de 2018 até o mês 10 de 2018, e um outro que trabalhou do mês 02 de 2018 até o mês 12 de 2018. Sendo que pra cada mês trabalho a situação dele pode ser diferente (em um mês ele pode estar Ativo, em outro mês de Férias, em outro Demitido, etc)

Já tentei usar GROUP BY e DISTINCT, mas da maneira que eu usei não deu certo.
A imagem abaixo ilustra um pouco da minha dúvida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço a todos.

Edit:
A query que estou usando atualmente é essa (eu adaptei de um exemplo que achei em um site, mas não me ajudou a resolver o problema):

```
SELECT TOP 200
  tabela1.ano,
  tabela1.mes,
  tabela1.matricula,
  tabela1.cpf,
  tabela1.nome_servidor,
  tabela1.cargo_ocupado,
  tabela1.funcao,
  tabela1.tipo_vinculo,
  tabela1.data_exercicio,
  tabela1.data_demissao,
  tabela1.situacao_funcional,
  tabela1.enquadramento_salarial,
  tabela1.orgao_lotacao,
  tabela1.carga_horaria,
  tabela1.numero_concurso
FROM 
  dbo.vw_portal_rhf_servidores tabela1
  LEFT JOIN dbo.vw_portal_rhf_servidores tabela2
  ON tabela1.matricula = tabela2.matricula
  AND tabela1.ano < tabela2.ano
  AND tabela1.mes < tabela2.mes
```

Eu não possuo o modelo da tabela, pois eu só recebo uma view de um outro lugar.

O resultado que eu gostaria de receber seria o da imagem abaixo, circulado em amarelo (eu sei que ficou estranho, mas eu não consigo exemplificar de uma maneira melhor):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit2:
(resolução)

Eu achei uma resolução, foi o seguinte código:

```
SELECT
  tabela1.ano,
  tabela1.mes,
  tabela1.matricula,
  tabela1.cpf,
  tabela1.nome_servidor,
  tabela1.cargo_ocupado,
  tabela1.funcao,
  tabela1.tipo_vinculo,
  tabela1.data_exercicio,
  tabela1.data_demissao,
  tabela1.situacao_funcional,
  tabela1.enquadramento_salarial,
  tabela1.orgao_lotacao,
  tabela1.carga_horaria,
  tabela1.numero_concurso
FROM 
  dbo.vw_portal_rhf_servidores tabela1
  LEFT JOIN dbo.vw_portal_rhf_servidores tabela2
  ON tabela1.matricula = tabela2.matricula
  AND CONCAT(tabela1.ano, tabela1.mes) < CONCAT(tabela2.ano, tabela2.mes)
  WHERE tabela2.matricula is NULL
```

Espero que possa ajudar quem estiver enfrentando o mesmo problema, ou algum problema semelhante. Obrigado a todos que se dispuseram a ajudar :D

Comment: Matheus tudo bom? Poste o modelo da sua tabela, a sua query atual e deixe um exemplo de retorno que você gostaria de obter para que possamos lhe ajudar. Aqui no site dê preferência para códigos do que imagens, senão corre o risco de sua pergunta ser fechada, ok? Abraço :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis uma solução:

```
-- código #1
with servidores_seq as (
SELECT *, 
       seq= row_number() over (partition by matricula order by ano desc, mes desc)
  from dbo.vw_portal_rhf_servidores
  where ...
)
SELECT ano, mes, matricula, cpf, nome_servidor, cargo_ocupado, funcao,
       tipo_vinculo, data_exercicio, data_demissao, situacao_funcional,
       enquadramento_salarial, orgao_lotacao, carga_horaria,
       numero_concurso
  from servidores_seq
  where seq = 1;
```

Na primeira cláusula WHERE você acrescenta os filtros de seleção, caso sejam necessários.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia ser algo assim:

```
SELECT TOP 200
  tabela1.ano,
  tabela1.mes,
  tabela1.matricula,
  tabela1.cpf,
  tabela1.nome_servidor,
  tabela1.cargo_ocupado,
  tabela1.funcao,
  tabela1.tipo_vinculo,
  tabela1.data_exercicio,
  tabela1.data_demissao,
  tabela1.situacao_funcional,
  tabela1.enquadramento_salarial,
  tabela1.orgao_lotacao,
  tabela1.carga_horaria,
  tabela1.numero_concurso
FROM 
  dbo.vw_portal_rhf_servidores tabela1
  ON tabela1.matricula
  AND cast(tabela1.ano as varchar(4)) + "-" + cast(tabela1.mes as varchar(2)) 
  in (select max(cast(tabela2.ano as varchar(4)) + "-" + cast(tabela2.mes as varchar(2)))
  from dbo.vw_portal_rhf_servidores tabela2 where tabela2.matricula = tabela1.matricula)
```

Comment: Não funcionou amigo. Dá a seguinte mensagem: " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON' "

Comment: ON tabela1.matricula = tabela2.matricula